# Getting an expression error in Java

Tags: java

I've tried looking through other threads and tried fixing this error myself. Can you please assist me with the following Java code?
I'm getting the following error `error: illegal start of expression`

Sorry if I didn't post this question correctly I don't know where to find line numbering function on this forum.

```
import java.util.*;
public class PracFive {
    private static boolean continueGame()
    {
        System.out.println("Do you want to play again? (Y/N)");
        String answer = new Scanner(System.in).next();
        return answer.trim().toLowerCase().equals("y");
    }

    private static void playGame(List<String> names)
    {
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("List size: " + names.size());
        Random rand = new Random();

        int guessInt = rand.nextInt(names.size());
        String ComputersGuess = names.get(guessInt);

        boolean isWrong = false;
        int trial = 0;
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("A random color was chosen choose which one: ");

    while (isWrong)
    {
        trial++;
        String humanGuess = input.next();

        if (humanGuess.trim().toLowerCase().equals(ComputersGuess.toLowerCase()))
        {
            isWrong = false;
            System.out.println("Yeey! you got it");
            names.remove(guessInt);
        }else{
            System.out.println("Try again, dude!");
        }
        if (trial == 1){
            String firstletter = ComputersGuess.substring(0,1);
            System.out.println("First Letter is: " + firstletter);
        }else if(trial == 2){
            System.out.println("Number of letters: " + ComputersGuess);
        }else if(trial == 3){
            isWrong = false;
        }
    }

     public static main(String[] args) 
     {

        List<String> names = new ArrayList<>();

        names.add("Yellow");
        names.add("Red");
        names.add("Blue");
        names.add("Maroon");
        names.add("Pink");
        names.add("Purple");
        names.add("Black");
        names.add("Orange");
        names.add("White");
        names.add("Green");

        System.out.format("%d\t\t%s","Index", "Color name");
        System.out.println();

        int count = 0;
        for(String name: names)
        {
            System.out.format("%d\t\t%s",count++,name);
        }

        playGame(names);

        boolean isInterested = continueGame();

        while(isInterested)
        {
            playGame(names);
            isInterested = continueGame();
        }
    }
```

Comment: _i dont know where to find line numbering function on this forum_ - you can add a comment at the end of the line in question, e.g. `// <= this line`

Comment: a few opening/closing braces `{`, `}` are mismatched, missing. and `main`'s return type needs to be `void`

Comment: You seem to be missing `}` before the `main()` method to close the `playGame()` method.

Comment: Are you using IDE like IntelliJ or Eclipse? If you pasted exactly what you have in PracFive.java file then you need additional `}' before `main` method (that would close `playGame`) and should add return type to `main` method e.g. `public static void main(String[] args)`

Comment: Please paste your error log from the console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are getting error because you are trying to format string to double. And your problem is here

System.out.format("%d\t\t%s","Index", "Color name");

remove or fix this line and also fix other problems that has been mentioned by others.